# Create picklist field with picklist values

Tags: webservices, metadata-api, metadata, java

I am using Metadata WSDL along with Partner WSDl to work on metadata API to create fields.

I am able to create fields of type text, checkbox, etc, but I need to create a picklist field and add picklist values to it.

Below is the source code i have written. I am not sure where to add the picklist values.

```
CustomField customField = new CustomField();
customField.setFullName("Account.customPickField__c");
customField.setLabel("customPickField");
customField.setType(FieldType.Picklist);

SaveResult[] results = metadataConnection.createMetadata(new Metadata[] {customField});
```

I have seen forums where people says to use

```
customField.setPicklist();
```

But this method is not available .

I am using a java application, to connection to a salesforce org with version 39.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the metadata XML, you will find that after Version 37 the picklist values are not stored as `picklistValue` inside `picklist` anymore. **They are stored as `value` inside `valueSetDefinition` wrapped in `valueSet`.** Please find the difference below.

Version <= 37

```
<fields>
    <fullName>Country__c</fullName>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Country</label>
    <picklist>
        <picklistValues>
            <fullName>USA</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </picklistValues>
        <picklistValues>
            <fullName>INDIA</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </picklistValues>
        <picklistValues>
            <fullName>Canada</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </picklistValues>
        <sorted>false</sorted>
    </picklist>
```

Verson >= 38

```
<fields>
    <fullName>Country__c</fullName>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Country</label>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>Picklist</type>
    <valueSet>
        <valueSetDefinition>
            <sorted>false</sorted>
            <value>
                <fullName>USA</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
            </value>
            <value>
                <fullName>INDIA</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
            </value>
            <value>
                <fullName>Canada</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
            </value>
        </valueSetDefinition>
    </valueSet>
</fields>
```

So you have to create same structure in your Java Code to create the Picklist with picklist values. Your java code should look like this.

```
CustomField field = new CustomField();
field.setType(FieldType.Picklist);
ValueSet vs = new ValueSet();
ValueSetValuesDefinition vd = new ValueSetValuesDefinition();
CustomValue[] cva = new CustomValue[2]; // The picklist contains two values
CustomValue cv1 = new CustomValue();
cv1.setFullName("Pick1"); // First picklist value
cv1.setDefault(false);
cva[0] = cv1;
CustomValue cv2 = new CustomValue();
cv2.setFullName("Pick2"); // Second picklist value
cv2.setDefault(false);
cva[1] = cv2;
vd.setValue(cva);
vs.setValueSetDefinition(vd);
field.setDescription("Created by Metadata API");
field.setLabel("Metadata API");
field.setFullName("Book__c.Metadata_API__c");
field.setValueSet(vs);
```

Comment: Related question; if you put a sniffer on the outgoing request how does it look like? I am trying to do the same but via the REST API and I am having difficulty finding the necessary metadata types such as ValueSet.

Answer (score 0):

Ran out of space, hence posting as an answer.

hello Saroj. I am trying to create Picklist field using Metadata API in Salesforce. It is similar to what you have posted but getting below error message. What am I missing?

**Error message:** You must specify either picklist, globalPicklist, or valueSet.

```
//Picklist field
MetadataService.CustomField field = new MetadataService.CustomField();
field.type_x = 'Picklist';
field.Description ='Created by Metadata API';
field.Label='Metadata API';
field.FullName='WorkOrder.Metadata_API__c';

//Custom Values
List<MetadataService.CustomValue> cva = new List<MetadataService.CustomValue>();
MetadataService.CustomValue cv1 = new MetadataService.CustomValue();
cv1.fullName = 'segmentA'; 
cv1.description = 'segmentA';
cv1.isActive = true;
cva.add(cv1);
MetadataService.CustomValue cv2 = new MetadataService.CustomValue();
cv2.fullName = 'segmentB'; 
cv2.description = 'segmentB';
cv2.isActive = true;
cva.add(cv2);

//Value Set Values Definition
MetadataService.ValueSetValuesDefinition vd = new MetadataService.ValueSetValuesDefinition();
vd.value = cva;

//Value Set
MetadataService.ValueSet vs = new MetadataService.ValueSet();
vs.valueSetDefinition = vd;
field.valueSet = vs;
```